# "Authorization header is missing" error when fetching amazon music api

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to search a song name on the amazon music api to pull its metadata. I am passing the headers and search parameters exactly like the documentation describes, but I keep getting an error saying my authorization header is missing even though it is clearly being defined and passed to the fetch function. Can someone help me figure out why this error keeps occurring?

Here is my javascript

```
const getAmazonMusicLinkFromSongInfo = async (amazonAuthToken, clientID) => {
    var searchQuery = {
        "searchFilters": [
            {
                'field': 'name',
                'query': 'soja'
            }
        ]
    }
    searchQuery = JSON.stringify(searchQuery)
    
    const searchParameters = {
        method: 'POST',
        Headers: {
            /*'access-control-allow-origin': '*',*/
            'x-api-key': clientID,
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + amazonAuthToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        },
        data: searchQuery
    }

    const amazonMusicFetchResponse = await fetch('https://api.music.amazon.dev/v1/search/tracks', searchParameters)
    const amazonMusicFetchResponseJson = await amazonMusicFetchResponse.json()
    console.log(amazonMusicFetchResponseJson)
    return amazonMusicFetchResponseJson;
}


getAmazonMusicLinkFromSongInfo(amazonAuthToken, clientID);
```

Comment: Note that YOU cannot set the `access-control-allow-origin` headers. That is for the TARGET to do

Comment: `amazonAuthToken` definitely has a value in it right? Have you also tried with `headers` instead of `Headers` (not sure if fetch worries about capitalization, but the docs list the option as `headers` with a lowercase `h`)

Comment: Assuming this isn't running In a browser (i.e. no network tab), perhaps use [this network monitor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/network-activity-viewer) package to see http(s) action in motion

Comment: @NickParsons i changed it to lowercase 'headers' and now its giving me a new error "unable to give access to customer, check access token" even though i just generated a new access token minutes ago

Answer (score 0):

I tried to crosscheck the API request parameters, it is correct. The problem is may be from `searchParameters` object.
[image: API Endpoint seems to be correct]

Make the changes as following:

```
const searchParameters = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {   //<<<------Change 'Headers' to 'headers'
            /*'access-control-allow-origin': '*',*/
            'x-api-key': clientID,
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + amazonAuthToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        },
        data: searchQuery
    }
```

```js
(async () => {
var searchQuery = {
        "searchFilters": [
            {
                'field': 'name',
                'query': 'soja'
            }
        ]
    }
   const data={
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'x-api-key': "clientID",
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + "amazonAuthToken",
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(searchQuery)
  }
  const rawResponse = await fetch('https://api.music.amazon.dev/v1/search/tracks', data );
  const contents = await rawResponse.json();
  console.log(contents);
})();
```